# Error while extracting twitter data

Tags: r, twitter

```
load("twitter authentication.Rdata")
registerTwitterOAuth(cred)
error: ROAuth is no longer used in favor of httr, please see ? setup_twitter_oauth
```

I am trying to extract tweets by following steps given [here](http://blog.credera.com/business-intelligence/twitter-analytics-using-r-part-1-extract-tweets/), but I am getting the above error.

I'm using `R Studio V3.1`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RStudio on a Server: ROAuth no longer used in favor of httr? \[Twitter API\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496345/rstudio-on-a-server-roauth-no-longer-used-in-favor-of-httr-twitter-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there migt have been some changes in the package. An up-to-date tutorial on how to connect to the twitter API via R can be found here: http://www.gis-blog.com/download-manage-and-visualize-twitter-data-with-r/